# What happened to AssemblyDescription in Windows 7?

Tags: .net, windows-7

We were using the AssemblyDescription attribute to add notes to our assemblies (e.g. fix/branch info).

The text was visible on XP in the file Properties/Comments. However in Windows 7 this field has been hidden.

Is there a way to show this field in explorer or any other tool?

Does MS explain anywhere why this field was removed and what we should use instead? (AssemblyTitle?)

Comment: Why would that be a duplicate?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In my test assembly I have this defined in my AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("this is a description")]
```

I can use either of these lines to retrieve that text from the resultant assembly:

via PowerShell

```
(dir $path).VersionInfo.Comments
```

via C#

```
System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path).Comments
```

Comment: This works in powershell as well: *(dir <filepath>).VersionInfo | fl* where <filepath> is a full path to a file.

Comment: Nice one, Aardvark. More concise than my original PowerShell example. I'll take it a step further: (dir $path).VersionInfo.Comments

Comment: I dont understand how this answers the question...?  Is there a way to show it in windows explorer or not?

Comment: @SailingJudo "Is there a way to show this field in explorer **or any other tool**?" I was answering the latter part of the question.

Comment: This does not appear to work for me in Powershell 2. If I use Windows Explorer then I can see that AssemblyDescription has been correctly set; but if I use the Powershell script above, it returns an empty value.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to display AssemblyDescription in Windows 7 Explorer, you will need a custom shell extension, like the following:

- [VersionTab](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/118909/Windows-7-File-properties-Version-Tab-Shell-Extens)

Comment: PowerExt does not show the AssemblyDescription unfortunately.

Comment: Not sure why I thought it did. Thanks for the comment, I have updated my answer.